# Type not prefixed in runtime generated WSDL with CXF

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, cxf

I have a Java-first web service, integrated with Spring. The service interface is simple:

```
@WebService
public interface ContactService {

    public void addContact(@WebParam(name="contact") Contact contact);
    public List<Contact> listContact();
    public void removeContact(@WebParam(name="id") Integer id);
}
```

The implementation:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.foobar.contact.service.ContactService")
@Service
public class ContactServiceImpl implements ContactService {
    // methods
}
```

The model:

```
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD )
public class Contact {
    private Integer id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String telephone;
}
```

If I use the Maven plugin `cxf-java2ws-plugin`, the WSDL generated is correct. But without specifying the WSDL, the one CXF generates at runtime does not work.

For example, in the one generated by `cxf-java2ws-plugin`, the return type is properly prefixed with `tns`:

```
<xs:complexType name="listContactResponse">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:contact"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

In the one generated at runtime, `contact` is not prefixed, so it cannot be resolved:

```
<xsd:complexType name="listContactResponse">
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="return" type="contact"/>
</xsd:sequence>
```

Both WSDLs do contain the proper complex type `contact`.

How do I tell CXF/JAX-WS that `contact` is the type it defined in the WSDL?

Answer (score 1):

look at the xsd, wich generates automatically with wsdl:

```
schemaLocation="http://<server>:<port>/<app>/<webservice>?xsd=1
```